# protection against CSRF without hidden input in all forms

Tags: php, html, security, csrf

I wonder if I could put the crsf token in `<head>`, on a meta tag or something, and then access it on my server. It would really simplify the process and make it more transparent. I just don't know how. I was really hoping to do this without javascript involved.

I think rails implements something like that...with etags maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many methods listed on the [CSRF prevention cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). One that doesn't require a hidden field on every form,  is [to check the referer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Checking_Referer_Header).   Keep in mind the lack of the referer should be considered a CSRF attack and may cause problems with some privacy browser addons (which is very uncommon).

Comment: isn't the referer informed by the client? how can that be safe?

Comment: @hugo_leonardo  exactly, The Victim's browser will report where the request originated from.  Although it is trivial to spoof the referer header,  it is not possible to spoof the referer in a CSRF attack.

Comment: What if someone is able to forge requests from the same site, e. g. by exploiting a very limited XSS vulnerability like `<img src="…">`?

Comment: @Gumbo XSS bypasses all anti-csrf systems except a captcha or asking for the user's password.  That being said,  state changes should never be GET based,  and if an attacker can control a URL (like the path to an avatar on a message board) and use this for state changes then that is clearly a problem,  but also not very common.  The OP should read the csrf prevention cheat sheet and use the method that is right for them.

Comment: Cheat sheet link is dead. I assume it was this content: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental purpose of a CSRF token is that it is delivered back to the server with each form submission. You deliver the unique token to a page, and when the form on that page is submitted the token comes back with it.

If you don't include the token on the form (or use JavaScript to programmatically add a token to the form that's currently elsewhere on the page) it will not be sent back to the server.

Perhaps the better question is: what is it you're really trying to accomplish? In other words, why would you not want to include a CSRF token within the form? What's the disadvantage you'd like to overcome in your scenario?

Comment: I want to make the protection transparent in my framework. It's just annoying to put a token in every form. Just trying to find a more automated alternative...

Comment: @hugo_leonardo — Sounds like you want to have a form helper function in your framework.

Comment: Even more transparent. haha ~ can I use cookies for that? It sounds like the same concept to me: generate a token, get token back, refresh token when necessary...

Comment: No, you can't use cookies. The point of CSRF protection is that is a user is "tricked" into submitting a request to your app that the token is not included because they form was not submitted. But if they cookie exists from a previous submit, then the cookie will automatically be submitted with the forged request, rendering the CSRF protection ineffective.

Comment: The automated alternative would have to be part of the specific framework you're using. Perhaps you can tag your question with the name of that framework and we can more specifically address how you might modify it to do this automatically.

Comment: To add to Jason Dean's comment, cookies are the exact opposite of CSRF protection. That's not to say that cookies are inherently unusable, though, and in your application they may provide perfectly adequate protection. Cookies CAN be used to guarantee that the visitor has authenticated; they CANNOT be used to guarantee that a specific request is authorized. If your application takes requests like "withdraw money from my bank account", cookies are unacceptable. If your requests are more like, "Add 'get milk' to my to-do list" you may not need to worry so much about CSRF protection.

Comment: It's a personal framework... ~ well...every user would have it's own cookie that is available only for them and in my domain only. I don't see how can someone can use the cookie elsewhere to fake a request... (I would protect the cookie against XSS of course...)

Comment: If it's your personal framework, simply add the appropriate code to your library that outputs forms. This is a non-problem. But it sounds like you do not understand what CSRF is. Suppose that you have an authentication cookie for Facebook. Now here on Stack Overflow I cannot access that cookie or use it in any way. But I could put a link here to `facebook.com/post-to-my-wall.php?I+am+an+idiot`. When you click that link, your browser will make that request *with your authentication cookie* and the message will appear on your wall. That's a CSRF attack.

Comment: By contrast, CSRF tokens are unique to every *form*, not to every *user*. Here Facebook would generate a "Post to My Wall" form and provide you a unique token each time it's rendered. Now even if you are authenticated and even if you have that form open, my link here on Stack Overflow cannot possibly include the unique token you have at this precise moment, and my childish wall post will not occur.

Comment: VoteyDisciple you're right, i don't know why I put in my head that the cookie would not be sent if other page made the request. kk ~ so there's no way to put the token in `<head>` or something, instead of in each form? making the token unique to each page instead of each form isn't enough?

Comment: No. Only fields directly included as part of the `<form>` will be sent back to the server. Again, you can easily modify your framework code to do that automatically when generating form tags, but you cannot output them anywhere else on the page.

Comment: what if i output the code elsewhere on the page and make javascript put the code in my forms? that way i'm binding the token with the page and not the session...sounds good?

Comment: You still need a way of tracking the tokens, so you'd have to have some PHP code to store the generated CSRF token and link target in the session.

Answer (score 0):

The OWASP [csrf prevention](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#double-submit-cookie) guide details a technique using custom headers in which the server sets the csrf token in a cookie, using HMAC of a server side secret and some data unique to the session is common. Then the client writes this into a custom header on all requests to the server. No hidden inputs needed, no extra server state.